# Question on derivation step in portfolio replication under different borrowing and lending rates

Tags: stochastic-discount, derivation, stochastic-control

I'm currently trying to understand the derivation of a pricing PDE on a european claim that considers stock lending fees: [https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~paforsyt/hjb.pdf](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Epaforsyt/hjb.pdf)

In Appendix A.2, the author talks about stock lending income being a complicated transaction (and I agree, I was not really able to connect the cited paper to what happens there) and mentions that the holder of the short position "will not receive the proceeds of the short sale, but rather effectively receives $r_l−r_f$". I can accept this conceptually.

However, I can't understand the evolution of the bank account in A.7). Could someone please explain to me how that one can be derived?

Also (somewhat unrelated): Is it possible that there is no longer a risk-neutral measure for this market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting that
$$ B= V -\alpha S = V - (\alpha S)^+ + (\alpha S)^- $$
$$ = (V - (\alpha S)^+)^+ - (V - (\alpha S)^+)^- + (\alpha S)^-,$$
a clearer way to write  the dynamics of the *funding costs* (funding account by funding account, the borrowing one, the lending one, and the one that funds at lending rate corrected by stock borrowing fees) is:

$$dB = r^l (V - (\alpha S)^+)^+ dt - r^b (V-(\alpha S)^+)^- dt + (r^l - r^f) (\alpha S)^-dt , $$

where
$$ x^+ = x\cdot 1_{x\geq 0}, \: \: \: x^- = -x\cdot 1_{x< 0}, \: \: \: x=x^+ - x^-.$$

($S$ is assumed positive everywhere. All funding processes $F$ are assumed of the form $dF = rF dt$.)

We can then show that this is consistent with the paper's findings, expressed in terms of the function $\rho$,
$$\rho(x) = r^l\cdot 1_{x\geq 0} + r^b \cdot 1_{x<0}.$$

Indeed, if $\alpha \geq 0$, then

$$ dB = r^l (V-\alpha S)^+ dt - r^b(V- \alpha S)^- dt $$ $$= \rho(V - \alpha S)(V - \alpha S)  dt.$$

If $\alpha < 0$, then

$$ dB = r^l V^+dt - r^b V^- dt - (r^l-r^f)\alpha S dt $$ $$= (\rho(V)V - (r^l-r^f)\alpha S)dt.$$

Regarding your second question (that is related to the first), Bielecki and Rutkowski set up an *"arbitrage-free model, by proposing an essential extension of the classic definition, and*" and they "*provide sufficient conditions for the no-arbitrage property of
a market model under alternative assumptions about trading and netting*" in their paper [*Valuation and Hedging of Contracts with Funding Costs and Collateralization*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262416190_Valuation_and_Hedging_of_Contracts_with_Funding_Costs_and_Collateralization).